# powershell to bulk add a user as owner of exchange distribution group

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I need to add bulk add a user as an 'Owner' (Managed by:) to all distribution groups in my Exchange 2010 environment. My initial thought via PowerShell would be pull a .csv of all distros with the current Owners and then add the user in the .csv then import via PowerShell back in.

Not exactly sure how I can go about doing this. There is about 700 distros that this person needs to be an 'owner' of.

Answer (score 2):

Via http://www.o-xchange.com/2014/10/add-user-as-manager-of-distribution.html

What I ended up doing was pulling a list of all the distro groups that I needed. Then following this http://www.o-xchange.com/2014/10/add-user-as-manager-of-distribution.html

Add a user as the manager of a distribution group without removing existing managers via Exchange PowerShell.
Scenario:  Add a user as the manager of a distribution group without removing existing managers via Exchange PowerShell. If you were to use the Set-DistributionGroup command with the -managedby switch, it would remove the existing managers and set the managers you specified in the switch.  To add the user jdoe1 as a manager and not remove the existing managers from the distribution group 'HQ-All Employees', run the following PowerShell commands below.

```
$Group = Get-DistributionGroup "HQ-All Employees"
$Managers = $Group.ManagedBy
$User = Get-User  jdoe1
$Managers += $User 
Set-DistributionGroup "HQ-All Employees" -Managedby $Managers -
BypassSecurityGroupManagerCheck
```

Excel Magic: If you have an Excel sheet full of groups in Column A and wish to add jdoe1 as the manager to each of those groups, copy the Excel formula below and drag it down for the entire list of groups. The value of each cell will create the Powershell command that you will need for each group.  Copy the cells (the cell values) and Paste it into Exchange PowerShell.  Each command is separated by a ; so the 5 PowerShell commands needed will fit into one Excel Cell and fit on one PowerShell line for each group.

```
="$Group= Get-distributiongroup """&A2&"""; $Managers= $group.managedby; 
$User=Get-User jdoe1;$Managers+=$User;Set-DistributionGroup """&A2&""" -
managedby $Managers -BypassSecurityGroupManagerCheck"
```

Answer (score 1):

The command for setting the owner of a DG is quite straight forward

```
Set-DistributionGroup -Identity <GroupName> -ManagedBy <Existing Owner, New Owner>
```

This MS article provides sufficient detail on changing the owners

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd638201(v=exchg.141).aspx

```
    Get-DistributionGroup | Export-csv -Path "C:\filename.csv" -NoTypeInformation

    $Distribution_Groups = import-csv "C:\filename.csv"
    $NewOwner = "owner@contoso.com"

    foreach ($Group in $Distribution_Groups){
        Set-DistributionGroup -Identity $Group.alias -ManagedBy @{Add=$NewOwner} 
     }
```

**Explanation**

The first line will get all the DG's and places them in a CSV file

The loop goes through the CSV and uses the alias value as the identifier for the set command.

The ManagedBy property is MultiValue which means we can use 'add' and 'remove' to update.

I don't have access to a test Exchange environment, so definitely test properly.

Comment: What I ended up doing was pulling a list of all the distro groups that I needed. Then following this http://www.o-xchange.com/2014/10/add-user-as-manager-of-distribution.html

Answer (score 1):

Similar to SDBaret, only using the .Name property:

```
$DistGroups = (Get-DistributionGroup).name

ForEach ($DistGroup in $DistGroups){
    Set-DistributionGroup -identity $DistGroup -ManagedBy @{Add="jsmith@contoso.com"}
}
```